# Apache: proxy to unix socket named in URL

Tags: apache, sockets, unix, proxy

I am building a setup, where a host runs a bunch of Docker containers for testing different code branches, and I want to access the running webserver in the containers.

All containers run on `host`. Each container serves a web application through a unix socket on the host, e.g. `/var/sockets/<socket_name>`.

What I want is for apache on `host` to proxy to the containers based on the url, so that when I `GET https://<host>.com/<socket_name>/my_url`, apache proxies to `<socket_name>` the request: `GET https://<host>.com/my_url`. That is, it recognizes the socket name in the url, rewrites the url and sends it to that socket.

Is this possible? I am still reading through documentaion, but cannot seem to find any hints

Comment: Apache supports proxying to unix sockets since 2.4.x . How exactly, well... I found your question looking for the answer with google. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Based on various docs on the net, the idea is to encompass both `mod_proxy` and `mod_rewrite` in two steps, namely, URL shall be processed to extract socket name and to be rewritten without that part, and proxy shall be done based on the new (shortened) URL and the socket name.

Here is how it *could* look like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule      /(.*)/(.*)  http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$2    [P]
ProxyPass        /           unix:/var/sockets/$1.sock|http://%{HTTP_HOST}/
ProxyPassReverse /           unix:/var/sockets/$1.sock|http://%{HTTP_HOST}/
```

I ground my proposal on `(.*)` expressions which shall extract the two parameters of interest. Then we rewrite the URL and, by means of `P` flag we denote that it the result is to be passed to proxy. Later we specify two identical `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` and specify Unix socket path, pipe `|` separator and host base address.

I hope this could work or at least give you some sketch of what shall we look for.

Comment: I'll see if I can find time to try this out. In the meantime, I've created a small python webapp that simply redirects the urls

Comment: OK, Python webapp might be a suitable solution too.

Comment: You might want to use `(\w+)` for the first regex group to make extra sure that no malicious string is matched that might be used to access other files than you expect.

Comment: This doesn’t work for me because the `$1` in the socket path is not replaced but a socket path with the literal `$1` is tried to open. I already achieved the same thing with `LocationMatch` and `ProxyPassMatch` but mod_rewrite was told to be more powerful. How to enable interpolation of `$1`?